# To store as a class parameter or normal php variable

Tags: php, class

I am new to OO concepts in PHP. I have a class called MY_ controller which is my base class. All classes extend this class. I am using MVC architecture. I am using caching in my system now. So i load the cache variable in the constructor of my base class. I use normal php variable like `$cacheVariable` in my function to store the value from cache. I was wondering if it would serve any help if i store it as a class parameter and use like `$this->cacheVariable`? In each function i get cache value like `$this->cache->get('cacheVariable');` will it help if i get value from `$this->cacheVariable`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use $cacheVariable anywhere else besides your constructor you'll want to use $this

```
public function __construct() {
    //...
    $this->cacheVariable = $this->cache->get('cacheVariable');
    //...
}
```

Also remember, if you want your children classes to inherit this variable from your base class you will need to set it as either public or protected. If it's private children will not inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "class variable" I assume you are referring to a property (property of an instance=. Note the difference:

if you have a class, say MyClassA, then in your scripts you will instantiate that class using the operator new (depending on your PHP version you can use a different [constructor syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) it changed since PHP-5.3.0):

```
<?php
class MY_controller{
  public $cacheVariable;

  // constructor
  function MY_controller($aValue){
     // constructor code which loads cacheVariable, for example with parameter
     $this->cacheVariable = $aValue;
  }

  public function someFunction(){
    //... some code, then access the property
    $cv = $this->cacheVariable;
  }
}

$aController = new MY_controller(42);
?>
```

As you inherit from MY_controller, every **instance** of that class, will have access to cacheVariable through `$this->cacheVariable`.

The important thing I wanted to clarify is that it is an **instance** property, not a class one. For further reference on OOP in PHP, refer to the [properties section in PHP's OOP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and the [inheritance section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate only one instances of your controller (derived from your main controller), its a conceivable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the better idea is getting variable directly from cache service everywhere you want in your class and don't keep it as a class property. The reason is simple: let's say value of some key from cache will be changed (or expires) in the other place than your class. If you have this value as class property you need to keeping eye on it every time you access this value but if you retrieving it from cache you just don't care (because the cache cares if value of some key doesn't changed or expired).